# How to prevent SWR revalidating if key changed in SWR hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I have issue when using useSWR/useSWRInfinite hook to fetch data. Specifically, there are 3 variables in key of swr hook that I get and it changes whenever.

For example:

```
const usePost = (profile_id, from_id = '') => {
    const PAGE_LIMIT = 5;
    let { data, size, setSize, error, mutate, isValidating } = useSWRInfinite(
        (pageIndex, previousPageData) => {
            const currentPageIndex = pageIndex + 1;
            return `/posts/profile/${profile_id}?page=${currentPageIndex}&from_id=${from_id}`;
        },
        fetcher,
        {
            revalidateFirstPage: false,
        },
    );
    // more code
}
```

How can I **prevent** useSWRInfinite/useSWR revalidating even if **from_id** changes (excludes **profile_id** and **currentPageIndex**) ?